# how to replace \ with \\ in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, json

How do I escape backslash in java script .
This is what I need: ( tried from browser developer console)

```
var str = 'this is \\ test';
console.log(str);
```

This works fine and prints:
this is \ test

How do I do the same using replace function . Basically the above hard code (\) works . I want to have a generic solution for any string .

I tried below:

```
var str = 'this is \ test';
str=str.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
console.log(str);
```

but it just prints :
this is  test

My end goal is to pass a string with backslash  in a REST Json Body .
However it fails with HTTP 400 bad request .
So I am looking to escape the backslash before i pass it on to the Json body

So I am looking for a code to replace  \ with \

Comment: Do you have single backslash or double backslash in `str`? As you have specified `var str = 'this is \ test';` and `var str = 'this is \\ test';`. Both re different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: When you declare `var str = 'this is \ test';` `\ ` gets converted to ` ` at declaration, and it's too late to try any conversion from js execution. You would have to handle it from your code directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log the `str` you will see that there is no `\` in the actual string. It's just white space. I believe it is not possible replace something which is not even in the string.

```js
var str = 'this is \ test';
console.log(str);
```

Comment: What you are replacing here is two consecutive space characters, not \

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks. I changed the answser. The backslash `\\` doesn't exist in the string so no point in trying to replace it.